# How to find top 5 numbers in a data set and data associated with it?

Tags: d3.js

I am looking at some data on population size, like so:

```
const data = [
  { pop: 123, state: "NY" },
  { pop: 102, state: "TX" },
  { pop: 627, state: "FL" },
  { pop: 876, state: "WA" },
  { pop: 211, state: "MI" },
  { pop: 234, state: "CA" }
]
```

I am trying to find the top 5 numbers in a data set and then use the state name as part of a const in another part of code.

I have used something like this in the past:

```
const maxPop = d3.max(data, (d, i) => { return d.pop })
```

But I believe this will just return "876".

How would I use this to find the state name i.e. "WA" connected to the 876 in the data above? And then how would I find the other 4 top states?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using arrow functions, I assume you are fine with using ES6 syntax, because `d3.max` is just a convenience function. Here's a vanilla solution:

```js
// Just iterate over the array, if the value is larger than the current max,
// store that one instead. Otherwise, keep the current one
const maxByKey = (arr, key) =>
  arr.reduce((a, b) => (a[key] > b[key] ? a : b));

const data = [
  { pop: 123, state: "NY" },
  { pop: 102, state: "TX" },
  { pop: 627, state: "FL" },
  { pop: 876, state: "WA" },
  { pop: 211, state: "MI" },
  { pop: 234, state: "CA" }
]

console.log(maxByKey(data, 'pop'));
// logs { "pop": 876, "state": "WA" }
```

---

To get the top 5 states, I'd just sort the list and return the 5 biggest.

```js
let data = [
  { pop: 123, state: "NY" },
  { pop: 102, state: "TX" },
  { pop: 627, state: "FL" },
  { pop: 876, state: "WA" },
  { pop: 211, state: "MI" },
  { pop: 234, state: "CA" },
  { pop: 235, state: "CA" },
  { pop: 236, state: "CA" },
  { pop: 237, state: "CA" },
  { pop: 238, state: "CA" },
  { pop: 238, state: "CA" },
  { pop: 239, state: "CA" }
];

data.sort((a, b) => b.pop - a.pop);

// Data has been sorted, now remove all but the first occurrence of every state
// The logic behind this is that `i` is the index of `d` in the array, and
// indexOf always returns the first match. So if indexOf isn't equal to `i`, then
// `d` is not the first occurrence of that value in the list
const states = data.map((d) => d.state);
data = data.filter((d, i) => states.indexOf(d.state) === i);

console.log(data.slice(0, 5));
/*
[
  {
    "pop": 876,
    "state": "WA"
  },
  {
    "pop": 627,
    "state": "FL"
  },
  {
    "pop": 239,
    "state": "CA"
  },
  {
    "pop": 211,
    "state": "MI"
  },
  {
    "pop": 123,
    "state": "NY"
  }
]
*/
```

---

To get the top 5 states, ignoring duplicate state values, I'd try to "group" them first:

```js
const data = [
  { pop: 123, state: "NY" },
  { pop: 102, state: "TX" },
  { pop: 627, state: "FL" },
  { pop: 876, state: "WA" },
  { pop: 211, state: "MI" },
  { pop: 234, state: "CA" }
]

data.sort((a, b) => b.pop - a.pop);

console.log(data.slice(0, 5));
/*
[
  {
    "pop": 876,
    "state": "WA"
  },
  {
    "pop": 627,
    "state": "FL"
  },
  {
    "pop": 234,
    "state": "CA"
  },
  {
    "pop": 211,
    "state": "MI"
  },
  {
    "pop": 123,
    "state": "NY"
  }
]
*/
```

Comment: Sorting happens in place - it modifies the original object. Use `data.slice().sort(...)` to prevent changing data itself

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much for your help, really appreciate, a huge help on starting me on my journey - now to work out how to do the rest of it! haha.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `d3.max` you have to use [`d3.greatest`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array#greatest), which will return the whole object:

```js
const data = [{
    pop: 123,
    state: "NY"
  },
  {
    pop: 102,
    state: "TX"
  },
  {
    pop: 627,
    state: "FL"
  },
  {
    pop: 876,
    state: "WA"
  },
  {
    pop: 211,
    state: "MI"
  },
  {
    pop: 234,
    state: "CA"
  }
];

const max = d3.greatest(data, d => d.pop);

console.log(max)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
```